# query date ranges postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-range

I have the following postgresql table;

```
ID  Date
 1  [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
 2  [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
 3  [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
 4  [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
 5  [2000-01-01,2017-01-01)
 6  [2000-01-01,2017-01-01)
 7  [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
 8  [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
 9  [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
 10 [2017-01-01,2051-01-01)
```

How can I query in date ranges such that for June 2003 it returns ID 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the containment operator `<@`:

```
with my_table(id, dates) as (
values
    (1, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)'::daterange),
    (2, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)'),
    (3, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)'),
    (4, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)'),
    (5, '[2000-01-01,2017-01-01)'),
    (6, '[2000-01-01,2017-01-01)'),
    (7, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)'),
    (8, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)'),
    (9, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)'),
    (10, '[2017-01-01,2051-01-01)')
)

select *
from my_table
where '2003-06-01'::date <@ dates;

 id |          dates          
----+-------------------------
  5 | [2000-01-01,2017-01-01)
  6 | [2000-01-01,2017-01-01)
(2 rows)
```

Read about [Range Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html)

---

You can also check whether a date range (not a single date) is contained by `dates:`

```
where daterange('2003-01-01', '2003-12-31') <@ dates;
```

or whether a date range overlaps `dates:`

```
where daterange('2003-01-01', '2003-12-31') && dates;
```

Comment: how would query change if we just modify it to 2003 only, no month.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

use contains operator, eg:

```
postgres=# select '[2000-01-01,2017-01-01)'::daterange @> '2013.01.01'::date;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

so for you it would be smth like

```
select * from tbl where "Date" @> '2013.01.01'::date;
```